# Sonarqube code reports not getting generated

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The Jenkins build is successful for the maven goal which I have set it as -U clean install sonar:sonar in the job but however in Sonar dashboard there are no reports being generated. Can you please help on the same?

**Error**

Failed to execute goal `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar` (d
efault-cli) on project extension: Fail to extract sonar-runner-batch.jar: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: You appear to have pinned the version of the scanner to use (in your pom)...? Remove that & this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if Sonar server is up and running. Also you can check build logs which mentions publish path to sonar server

[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=JenkinsTestApplication%3AJenkinsTestApplication